# Excel create chart from date, hh, mm, ss columns

Tags: excel, charts

I have a csv file with the date and time (h,m,s) all split in separate columns. I would need to display the count in a chart with the appropriate date/time value. I really can't figure out how

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jqP6.png)

Comment: Display the count of what? What have you tried? Are you after code? This can be easily done with a pivot table.

Comment: it's the count of users (in the first column). I have tried aggregating the columns but having trouble in getting a date/time format (tried various custom). 
No code just Excel. All I need is a chart showing the user count at each date/time value

Comment: To what level of detail? Count for every minute value? Every Second value?

Comment: every second (this is for calculating requests/sec)

Comment: what is the "secs" column? are the seconds in the "ss" column?

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove blank rows or rows without dates, then create a pivot table. Drag date into the rows area, then hours below date, then minutes below hours, if that level of detail is desired.

Drag any field into the Values panel and set it to count. Create a chart from that.

If that does not do what you want, you need to **edit your question** with **A LOT** more detail to describe the desired output.

Edit: Another approach: construct a complete date/time value with a formula

```
=B1+time(0,0,C1)
```

(assuming that column C has time values in seconds.) Now create a pivot table with the new columns in rows and a count of CT in the Values. Build a chart from that.

If you need the X axis to be a time axis, you need to build a regular chart from the pivot table, not a pivot chart.

Comment: worked well thanks and was able to create a pivot chart. The issue I have is that after cell 224 the formula errors
[link](https://imgur.com/Rk5sZI2)

Comment: The reason it blew up is the value for the number of seconds is too large.  from MS help file on the time function:  `Second    Required. A number from 0 to 32767 representing the second. Any value greater than 59 will be converted to hours, minutes, and seconds.`

Comment: instead of `=B1+time(0,0,C1)` which is only using the seconds, use your columns D1,E1,and F1, in the time function `=B1+time(D1,E1,F1)`